# Deprecated variables migrating to Liferay 7.2

Tags: migration, liferay-7, liferay-aui, liferay-7.2

During theme migration from Liferay 7 to Liferay 7.2 I am getting following issues. Please tell me what to use in place of these deprecated variables?

```
$state-danger-text was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-info-bg was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-info-border was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-info-text was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-success-border was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-success-text was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-warning-border was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
    $state-warning-text was deprecated in Lexicon CSS 1.x.x and has been removed in the new Clay 2.x.x version
and many more...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you called `gulp upgrade` to get that output.

According to [the migration guide](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/updating-css-code) you simply need to remove these variables. They are defined in one of your theme files (e.g. `_variables_custom.scss`) and are not needed anymore.

Comment: But in my code, I am using some of these variables So what to use in place of them?

Answer (score 0):

theme migration to 7.2 will change the structure use following step

1. npm install -g generator-liferay-theme@9.x.x
2. npm install --save-dev liferay-theme-tasks@9.x.x
3. gulp upgrade
4. gulp init

then you are good to go.